# How to fix 'The entity type... requires a primary key to be defined'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I'm doing an internet scripting module which is based on C# and Visual Studio Code. Although it is taught in a very step-by-step approach, I'd been really struggling at the start of the module, I guess due to unfamiliarity with VSC, and also a tendency to get badly muddled and flustered at times. Anyway, I've improved quite a bit now, and the lecturer said he thought it would be beneficial for me to write my own VSC project based on my own database. That is definitely quite appealing to me, as I already have a database for my own use that I would like to work with, which would help my motivation and interest.

So I spent all day yesterday following the [video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQipYohiIK08QUR3M-ZHQLilP1ytSnhzF) through once again, but this time using my own database. I have done a lot, and the project builds fine, but there is obviously something wrong as when I try to run it, I get

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Item' requires a primary key to be defined.

I won't paste the entire error message, as it is massive, but it also makes reference to 'Program.cs:line 19'

Here is my code:

Here is my code:

**DHR.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

**DHR.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DHR
{
    public class DHR : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

        // protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder){
        // string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "DHR.db");
        // optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={path}");
        // }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "DHR.db");
            string CurrentDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string ParentDir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(CurrentDir).FullName;
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(ParentDir, "DHR.db");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={path}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
// using DHR;
// using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DHR
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DHR");
            // Items item = new Items();

            DHR db = new DHR();

            IQueryable<Item> items = db.Items;

            foreach (Item i in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.listing_id);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
// using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DHR
{
    public class Item //: DbContext
    {
        public int listing_id { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string catno { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public int release_id { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public string listed { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public string media_condition { get; set; }
        public string sleeve_condition { get; set; }
        public int weight { get; set; }
        public int format_quantity { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string basic_format { get; set; }
        public char label_type { get; set; }
        public char sleeve_type { get; set; }
        public char with_cover { get; set; }
        public char complete { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public decimal median_price { get; set; }
        public string style { get; set; }
        public string amaz { get; set; }
        public string feed_product_type { get; set; }
        public string binding { get; set; }
        public string vinyl_record_details { get; set; }
        public string condition_type { get; set; }
        public string shipping_group { get; set; }
        public string product_id { get; set; }
        public string product_id_type { get; set; }
        public bool image { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }

        // public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

        // protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        // {
        //     // string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "DHR.db");
        //     string CurrentDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        //     string ParentDir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(CurrentDir).FullName;
        //     string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(ParentDir, "DHR.db");
        //     optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={path}");
        // }

    }
}
```

**DHR.sql**

```
    --
    -- File generated with SQLiteStudio v3.2.1 on Fri Mar 19 15:39:12 2021
    --
    -- Text encoding used: System
    --
    PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    
    -- Table: Items
    CREATE TABLE Items (listing_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, artist STRING, title STRING, label STRING, catno STRING, format STRING, release_id INTEGER, price DECIMAL, listed STRING, comments STRING, media_condition STRING, sleeve_condition STRING, weight INTEGER, format_quantity INTEGER, location STRING, basic_format STRING, label_type CHAR (2), sleeve_type CHAR (2), with_cover CHAR (2), complete CHAR (1), country STRING, year INTEGER, median_price DECIMAL, style STRING, amaz STRING, feed_product_type STRING, binding STRING, vinyl_record_details STRING, condition_type STRING, shipping_group STRING, product_id STRING, product_id_type STRING, image BOOLEAN, image_url STRING);

[etc.]
```

Edit: forgot to mention, I tried...

```
[Key]
public int listing_id { get; set; }
```

...but I got...

> The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `listing_id` does not use a naming convention that EF recognizes, you [will have to define it as a key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) manually.

Comment: You have to add a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Comment: Note that `Ctrl + .`can realy help you out in these situations.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I already tried that, please see the edit to my OP. Thanks anyway. Edit - OK, I added the key *and* the reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. That seemed to work but I'm now getting 'no such table: Items'. I seem to be a bit further on though, so thanks for that.

Comment: I see your edit, but I don't see anything about adding the reference to the assembly that `[key]` is in.

Comment: @Crowcoder - wasn't aware of that, but I've added it now, TY. Now I'm getting 'no such table: Items' though. Edit - do I only need `: DbContext` in DHR.cs?

Comment: See the posted answer, you are not consistent with your table name either, your db set is configuring an Item table, not Items

Comment: @Crowcoder - but if I change it to `public DbSet<Items> Items { get; set; }` I just get "The type or namespace name 'Items' could not be found". The *class* is called Item, the *table* is called Items. I had them both as Items previously, but that wasn't working so I differentiated them.

Comment: @Crowcoder - OK, I found something weird. the .db file had been copied to the parent directory, but it was 0 bytes. So I copied the proper file over and it actually ran for a little but, but I then got 'Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.' I'm getting closer though.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Item` doesn't define a primary key - the solution is: **define a primary key**.

EF Core has a convention that a numeric column with the name of `Id` or `(Entity)Id` (here: `ItemId`) will be recognised as primary key automatically.

If you don't have either of these two columns - then you need to **manually** and explicitly define a column (or combination of columns) to be the primary key, by adding the `[Key]` data annotation to it.

So either add a `int Id` or `int ItemId` column to your `Item` class - or designate e.g. the `listing_id` column as primary key like this:

```
// use the DataAnnotation package - you might need to add it using NuGet
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 

[Table("Items")]
public class Item //: DbContext
{
    [Key]
    public int listing_id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: perhaps you missed my edit, but I already tried that, and I got "The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". By the way, that is not shown in the lecturer's demo videos where he does just the same thing I am trying to do with my database. You can see for yourself if you follow the link in my OP. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @double-happiness: you need to ensure to have a `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` at the beginning of your file - the `KeyAttribute` is defined in the data annotations library

Comment: Right, got that now, thanks. I'm now getting 'no such table: Items' though.

Comment: Well - what's the table called, in your database? You might need to add another data annotation `[Table("name-of-table-here")]` to your class ......

Comment: It is called Items. It's shown in the .sql file in the OP. Edit - do I only need `: DbContext` in DHR.cs?

Comment: And are you **sure** that it has been created and exists??

Comment: well, I just opened the database in SQLIteStudio, and it definitely contains the table Items. Maybe I'm not pointing to it correctly though? It is in the same folder as all the other files I've posted in the OP.

Comment: When you build and run your app - is that database file **In the same folder** as the `.exe` that you run?? Most likely not ..... you need to copy the database file to the output directory - by setting it's "Copy to Output" Property to "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer"

Comment: I'm not running an .exe. I'm not even at that stage yet. I'm just trying to run it from a VSC console.

Comment: OK, I found something weird. the .db file had been copied to the parent directory, but it was 0 bytes. So I copied the proper file over and it actually ran for a little but, but I then got 'Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.' I'm getting closer though.

Comment: @marc_s does VSC know how to provide enough of a UI for a csproj file that it offers a "copy to output directory" setting?

Comment: @double-happiness *I'm not running an .exe. I'm just trying to run it from a VSC console.* - it still builds and runs an exe, by the way

Comment: @CaiusJard: not sure - I'm not really familiar with VSC (just blindly assumed the OP was using VS "proper") ....

Comment: (Me too - I use it for JS/TS but VS for C#, was wondering how "like VS" VSC was)